# Bronze Hose Bibb with Galvanized Pipe

Tags: plumbing, exterior

Outside my home I have a capped-off galvanized pipe stub-out.  It connects 18 inches underground to PVC water pipe.  I would like to attach a common garden hose bibb (sillcock, spigot).  These are made of bronze.  Is there risk of galvanic corrosion between the bronze fixture and the galvanized pipe?  Should I install a dielectric union or use instead a stainless steel fixture?  I have not seen this elsewhere.  Other homes have these fixtures attached to galvanized steel.  There is no frost in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bronze is not going to create galvanic corrosion when attached to galvanized pipe.